# Is there a syntax to inherit the value of content in CSS and concatenate it?

Tags: css

I would like the `content` property to be concatenated instead of overriding.

```html
<div class="bear"></div>
```

```css
div::after {
  content: "hello";
}
.bear::after {
  content: " bear"; /* Here, I would like bear to be concatenated to "hello" instead of overriding it */
}
```

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: You can use `bear::before` and `bear::after`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'inherit' the content as such but you can pick up a CSS variable value.

This snippet sets the variable --content in the div setting and uses that in the .bear pseudo element as well as the div pseudo element.

```css
div::after {
  --content: "hello";
  content: var(--content);
}

.bear::after {
  content: var(--content) " bear";
  /* Here, I would like bear to be concatenated to "hello" instead of overriding it */
}
```

```html
<div class="bear"></div>
```

Comment: That's an interesting way of solving the problem, thank you ;)